# Checking NaN values in pandas dataframe with int8 columns

Tags: python, pandas, null

As was proposed in a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50877663/memory-efficient-way-to-store-bool-and-nan-values-in-pandas) I posed last week, a memory efficient way to store a column with values in the range `[True, False, NaN]` would be to use the `int8`-datatype to denote `True` as `1`, `False` as `0` and `NaN` as `-1`.

If I do this, what would be good practice to "redefine" pandas' `isnull()` methods to also take into account that, if a column in a dataframe has dtype `int8`, `-1` should be considered a null-value. I could think of defining a new function `def isnull(v)`, that returns if a value is NaN, or -1 in case of dtype `int8`, but I can imagine this will not be a very fast and efficient solution (given that the dataframe I am working with is multiple gigabytes big, and I want to be able to count the amount of "null"-values in a column/dataframe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be pretty fast...

**Timing for 100.000.000 rows series.**

```
In [84]: s = pd.Series(np.random.choice([1,0,-1], 10**8), dtype=np.int8)

In [85]: s.shape
Out[85]: (100000000,)
```

simulating `series.isnull()`:

```
In [86]: %timeit s==-1
87 ms ± 3.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [87]: %timeit s.values==-1
84.1 ms ± 2.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [88]: %timeit np.where(s==-1)
546 ms ± 14.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [89]: %timeit np.where(s.values==-1)
531 ms ± 2.78 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

simulating: `series.isnull().sum()`:

```
In [90]: %timeit (s==-1).sum()
1.39 s ± 38.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [91]: %timeit (s.values==-1).sum()
181 ms ± 1.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

PS please pay attention that for counting (summing) them the difference between `(s==-1).sum()` and `(s.values==-1).sum()` is pretty noticeable

Comment: Just to confirm, you'd use `num_null_values = (s.values == -1).sum()`.

Comment: @FHTMitchell, yeah, thank you! I missed the very last part: `and I want to be able to count the amount of "null"-values`